# On downloading a file from a AJAX PAGE the file has same name as the ajax page downloading it

Tags: ajax, jakarta-ee

*Hi,
   I am trying to write a Ajax page which decrypts an encrypted file on the server and downloads it. Now my code decrypts and downloads the file. But the problem is that the downloaded file has the same name as that of the Ajax Page.
Below is the code which downloads the file to the local machine. I have not included the decryption code in-order to avoid confusion.***

String fileName="/home/maclean/NetBeansProjects/SecureCloud/build/web/SecureCloud/"+Data.txt;

This line declares the files location on the server

```
        response.setContentType("APPLICATION/DOWNLOAD");
        response.setContentLength(in.available());
        int length;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];

           while ((length = in.read(buffer)) > 0){
                 data=new String(buffer);
              buffer =decryptCaesar.Decrypt(data,shiftKey).getBytes();
os.write(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
System.out.println(buffer);
 } 
 response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename="+FileName);
```

and this line downloads the file. But the downloaded file has the name AjaxRead.jsp which is the name of the Ajax page Where as the original name of the file is Data.txt

Do let me know what I am doing wrong and how to get the same file name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't specify a file name for the download, the browser chooses one (based on the current URL). You can override the file name by setting the HTTP header `Content-Disposition` as:

`response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=Data.txt")`.

Comment: I used this response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=Data.txt") But it still works the same way the file name is still the name of the Ajax Page

Comment: You can see above I have set the content deposition as the file name. So I guess that is not issue.

Comment: You do get a download (i.e. browse for file save) dialog from your browser, do you? And you suggest that the default/suggested file name is the jsp instead of the Data.txt?

Comment: I do get a dialog while downloading but the problem is it does not allow me to enter the file name. There are only two options either save or cancel

Comment: That's browser specific and doesn't directly relate to the question IMHO. The browser should honor the header and use the file name.Could you please include any other fields you set on the `response` object earlier in your code?

Comment: I have not set any other fields in the response. I get the dialog only in Mozilla. Rest all browser the file gets downloaded without any prompt